# Connect to Azure Storage account using User assigned managed identiry in Automation Account (using Azure RM modules)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-storage-account, azure-rm

I am trying to connect to Stoarge account in Azure automation account using Azure RM powershell module.

I am using below commands

```
Connect-AzureRMAccount -Identity    
$storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName  
$srcContext = $storage.Context    
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $srcContext -Container $containerName -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token
```

The last line always returns storage context not found.

I have provided MSI with required permissions on the resource group where storage account resides.

Comment: Better you share the complete script and error message if you are getting any. Also will be great if you tell us which AzureRM version you are selecting in Azure Automation Account.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt providing ClientId in my command and hence it was failing. While using user assigned MSI below is the command

Connect-AzureRMAccount -Identity - AccountId "MSI_client_Id"